# Which approach is good to insert a record IF NOT EXISTS VS @@ROWCOUNT = 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert a record into table if the record not exists.
I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE #EMP 
(
    EmpID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    EmpName VARCHAR(100),
    Designation VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #EMP (EmpName, Designation)
VALUES ('Ramesh', 'Teamlead'), 
       ('Suresh', 'Manager')
```

Now I want to insert a record by checking the record exists or not

I can one of these two approaches:

Approach #1:

```
DECLARE @EmpID INT

SELECT @EmpID = EmpID
FROM #EMP 
WHERE EmpName = 'Ramesh' AND Designation = 'Teamlead'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO #EMP (EmpName, Designation)
    VALUES ('Ramesh', 'Teamlead')
```

Approach #2:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
               FROM #EMP 
               WHERE EmpName = 'Ramesh' AND Designation = 'Teamlead')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #EMP (EmpName, Designation)
    VALUES ('Ramesh', 'Teamlead')
END
```

Can anyone suggest which one is the better of the two?

Thank you

Comment: personally i would use the second approach, its just cleaner (if you forget about the copy/paste error), the only thing i would change is that i would switch the `NULL` To `1` but this is just my personal taste

Comment: Both are bad because they require *two* queries.

Comment: Learn good habits. Start using terminators with ever statement. Use `SET` to assign scalar values generally - people are often surprised when the SELECT statement used to query for a single value actually returns multiples and has unintended effects.

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach is flawed, you check for `'Ramesh'` but if they don't exist also `INSERT` `'Suresh'`, who might already exist.

I would personally suggest doing it all in one statement. Something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO #EMP (EmpName, Designation)
SELECT EmpName,
       Designation
FROM (VALUES('Ramesh','Teamlead'),
            ('Suresh','Manager'))V(EmpName, Designation)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #EMP E
                  WHERE E.EmpName = V.EmpName
                    AND E.Designation = V.Designation);
```

As mentioned by [@DanGuzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman), this does pose a problem (as do yours) that it could suffer race conditions (though with a local temporary table this would not be an issue). One method would be to therefore change the isolation level to serializable prior to the statement:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

Alternatively, you could use the hint `HOLDLOCK` on the table in the `NOT EXISTS`, which would be by using `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`.

Comment: Although not an issue with local temp tables, I just want to point out that the `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS` method is vulnerable to race conditions with concurrent inserts unless additional measures like transactions, serializable isolation, or locking hints are employed.

Comment: Good point, @DanGuzman, I did gloss over this due to the fact that the OP is using a temporary table.

Comment: Already the first 2 records available in table. I just provided for understanding of data only. Now I want to further insert the records and also I want to implement this logic in sp's

Comment: Feel free to point out if I'm incorrect in the above amendment, @DanGuzman .

Comment: So, I assume, you using a table type parameter, @SasiBhushanaRao , so that you can `INSERT` multiple rows. I'm not sure what your comment is trying to state; the fact that you want to implement the logic in a procedure just means you have a (table type) parameter instead of a `VALUES` clause, and your table is presumably *not* a local temporary table.

Comment: Here I am not using Temporary table. Just for showing the demo I used it. I am using permanent table. What I want to tell you is I just want to insert a record but before inserting I need to check whether the record exists already or not. If the record already exists I don't want to insert

Comment: And that is what my answer does, @SasiBhushanaRao , and in a different method to either of the one's you use (because it's just one query, not 2).

Comment: I am really sorry. I corrected the query in second approach. Actually I want to insert 'Ramesh' record only.

Comment: So just use scalar parameters instead, @SasiBhushanaRao . I don't see the problem here; the answer answers the question you have asked. if you don't know how to now implement the above in a procedure you need to post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), showing your attempts and explaining why they aren't working.